# Prove/disprove: Let $p(x) \neq 0$ be a polynomial and $\deg(P)<n$. Let $A_{n\times n}$ be a matrix such that $p(A)=0$. Then $A$ is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra

It's an HW question.

> Prove / disprove: Let $p(x) \neq 0$ be a polynomial and $\deg(p)<n$. Let $A_{n\times n}$ be a matrix such that p(A)=0. Then $A$ is singular.

I don't have a clue. Maybe something with Cayley–Hamilton?

Hint?

Comment: What do you bean by $p(x)=\neq 0$ ? That $p$ is not the zero polynomial ? That $p$ has no real zeors ? Are you working over the real numbers ?

Comment: I assumed that he meant that $p$ has no real zeros

Comment: @DietrichBurde If the question meant that $p$ has no complex zeros, then it becomes a trivial application of the fundamental theorem of algebra.  The other possibility is that it simply is meant to say $p$ is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Anyway, your example is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample:** take $p(x) = x^2 + 1$, and take
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0}
$$

Comment: $\deg(p)<n$ Is it?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

Let $ p(x) = x - 1$ and consider $ I_{2 \times 2} $. This matrix is clearly not singular, however $ p(I_{2 \times 2}) = 0 $, and $ \deg p = 1 < 2 $.

More generally, if $ A $ is a diagonalizable $ n \times n $ matrix and $ m_A $ is its minimal polynomial, then $ \deg m_A = n $ if and only if $ A $ has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: But $p(x)=x-1=0$ when $x=1$. I thought the question demands $p(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I admit the wording here is a bit vague, and I still am not sure what it means. Anyway, @Omnomnomnom 's counterexample fits for both cases.

Comment: I assumed $ p(x) \neq 0 $ meant that $ p(x) $, as a polynomial, was not the zero polynomial. If you want a polynomial which has no roots in your field, then @Omnomnomnom's example is the simplest in $ \mathbb{R} $.